# C# send "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" packet in Windows universal application

Tags: c#, sockets, http, network-programming, webrequest

I am working on a Windows universal application. I am using StreamSocketListener to listen packets and the function below is fired when a packet is available:

```
private async void ProcessRequestAsync(StreamSocket socket)
{

    StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder();

    using (IInputStream input = socket.InputStream)
    {             
        byte[] data = new byte[BufferSize];
        IBuffer buffer = data.AsBuffer();
        uint dataRead = BufferSize;
        while (dataRead == BufferSize)
        {
            await input.ReadAsync(buffer, BufferSize, InputStreamOptions.None);
            request.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, (Int32)buffer.Length));
            dataRead = buffer.Length;
        }

String message = request.ToString();

....

}
```

After I have received the message, I would like to respond back with a "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" packet.

I believe I can use the WebRequest or WebResponse class to send the success 200 OK packet, but I am not sure what method and headers to use. The code I use to send http packets:

```
String add = "http://" + IP + ":" + 5400 + "/";

WebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(add);

//HTTP 200 OK message seems to not have method name, however I get runtime error when I assign the Method to null or empty.
request.Method = "POST";

//I have commented the line below because the "HTTP 200 OK" message seems to not have any content
//dataStream.Write(ByteArray, 0, ByteArray.Length);

Stream dataStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:** This is the HTTP response I am trying to achieve:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Linux UPnP/1.0  (WDCR:Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0)
Connection: close
```

Comment: WebRequest cannot write to an existing stream. This has no chance of success. Why are you writing your own HTTP listener anyway? Is there no library that works on Windows Universal?

Comment: I am fairly new to universal apps. It seems like there is no HttpListener equivalent for universal apps. I have been searching for days and I've found StreamSocketListener as the only way.

Comment: Well, generating an HTTP response is extremely easy. It's just a short ASCII string. Btw, your receive loop is broken because you are not using the return value from ReadAsync.

Comment: When ReadAsync returns I am reading the buffer length 2 lines below (dataRead = buffer.Length;), and that is my exit condition from the loop. Did you point at that? or you meant something else when you said broken? Regarding HTTP response, I will add to this post with the "HTTP 200 OK" message I am trying to create. Could you show me how to generate that response?

Comment: Well, ReadAsync might read just one byte even if more are coming. You need to deal with that.

Comment: Can't you just `someStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("200 OK\n"))` or something?

Comment: Thank you that solved my problem! Converting plain HTTP message text into byte array worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem after trying Mr. B's and usr's suggestions:

In order to send the following "HTTP OK 200" packet:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Linux UPnP/1.0  (WDCR:Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0)
Connection: close
```

Code:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
str.Append("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");    
str.Append("Server: Linux UPnP/1.0 (WDCR:Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0)\r\n");
str.Append("Connection: close\r\n");
str.Append("\r\n");

byte[] response = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str.ToString());

await socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(response.AsBuffer());
```